# Font Typeface doesn't work

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf"); 
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

I am unable to see the textview typeface changed. I have "font.ttf" file in assets folder.
Basically, I am intended to show "Urdu" word in that textview (requirement) and therefore added urdu font in assets. Yet it is showing me "WORD" in English.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If the text of the `TextView` is `"WORD"` then using the urdu font will usually still show you `"WORD"`. Just with a little bit different looking characters. Very few fonts don't have the latin letters (Windings & co.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android doesn't support the full range of ttf fonts. [Here](http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font) is a font that I have used personally in my app. Try using this instead. If this one works, and your urdu one doesn't then your code it correct, and Android does not support your font. If neither work, then something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I replaced urdu font with this ds-digital font, and I got the result.
Can you please find me urdu font that work with android?

Comment: I don't think there are any Urdu fonts that are compatible with Android, or if there are, I haven't come across them yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/burnstown_dam.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);


    Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Kasheeda.ttf");
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    textView.setTypeface(tf1);
    textView.setText("Your Font Language Here");
```